# What is the meaning of "for" in this sentence

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

What is the meaning of "for" in this sentence

> Today many Jews no longer hold to a personal messiah, but hope for a
>   messianic age of justice and truth. **For** the Jews the coming of the
>   Messiah or the messianic age still lies in the future.

[Source](https://www.biblica.com/resources/bible-faqs/do-jews-and-christians-basically-have-the-same-religion/)

Comment: Would it help if the sentence was written as "The coming of the Messiah or the messianic age still lies in the future for the Jews"?

Comment: Yeah. But what does for mean here. I know it's grammatically right. But can i get some source. That what does it exactly mean. Because if i translate this from my native language. It'd be To in place of For

Comment: I think it's about their thinking. That they think that coming of the messiah is a future thing

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. The meaning is like that of "in the opinion of the Jews" or "its the belief of the Jews". Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. Now it does. But i wish i could get some source. Because I googled it but i couldn't find this meaning of for. For opinion/thinking

Comment: One answer may be that this use of 'for' could be classified as a 'grammaticised' preposition, the kind that do not express the usual sense of spatial relations, beneficiary or whatever. In other words, where they are placed in sentences depends not on what they mean but entirely on the rules of grammar.

Comment: What is your native language, user 65161? That might help some of us explain it if any of us should be familiar with your language. Also, I hope that my answer to your "shall/may" controversy might have helped you out.

Comment: Yes it did. Btw whoever edited this question. Highlighted wrong 'for'. So i reedited it

Answer (score 3):

To "hope for" = To "want", To "desire", To "dream of"

> "I hope for world peace."

A similar usage is

"to hope the best for" [a person]

> "We hope the best for your grandmother who is in the hospital."

Comment: I agree with this answer. The "for" is part of an idiomatic expression "to hope for", which means "to desire".

Comment: I love how much *I* am learning on this site _while_ helping others.  I didn't know the full [definition of _idiomatic_](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Dictionary#dobs=idiomatic) until I just read your comment and then finaly looked it up.  :)  And hey, "_native speaker_", that's _me_! . . .  I am the native speaker.  But I am not the Native speaker.